# Google maps drawing routes jittery

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to create an app and part of the app requires tracking a user walk route. The problem is the route is all over the place with my GPS. The walk I'm tracking will be about 15 minutes and around a city block or so. Accuracy isn't of the utmost importance but want it to be semi accurate.

Are there any good ways to make a cleaner looking route?

[image]

Comment: cleaner in what way? Do you want a better UI? Or is the route you are getting is off from the actual route? Please be specific.

Comment: So this was simply me waking around the block. So the route is wrong and not smooth enough even if it was right

Comment: can you please show the implementation of routes? how are you calculating routes?